# How to scrape data from website which is populated using js?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape post data ( likes, shares, image, etc ) from sharechat.com but the problem is I cannot find image URL of posts using Selenium as I suspect it uses Javascript to populate it.

I have tried playing around with Selenium to find the outermost HTML (displayed HTML) and I got all the other post information like the number of likes, shares, comments, etc but I am unable to get store Image as I cannot find its URL.

I am doing this for social network research for sentiment analysis and recommendation trends, so I expect to scrape the post data along with tags and number of likes, shares, etc. I am only failing at scraping out tags and URL of images.

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00004942685241013284) is geckodriver file you will need to run. 
Here's [my code](https://ideone.com/ZzESLQ):

```
import sys
import csv
import os
import time
import urllib
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
serviceurl = 'https://sharechat.com/trending/Hindi'

files = "dataset_link_1.txt"
if not os.path.exists(files):
    file(files, 'w').close()
enter = open(files,'w');

url = serviceurl
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\CHIT CHAT\Scrapper\geckodriver');
driver.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
driver.get(url);
driver.implicitly_wait(3) #gives an implicit wait for 10 seconds
while driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") != 'complete':
    pass;

for i in range(1,20):

    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height


        var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/a/div[3]/div[1]"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
        print(var) #No of watches
        enter.write("Total No of views:\n%s\n" %(var));

        var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/a/div[1]/div[1]/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
        print(var) #Title
        enter.write("Title:\n%s\n" %(var));

        var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
        print(var) #owner bio
        enter.write("Writer's Bio:\n%s\n" %(var));

        var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[1]/strong"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
        print(var) #owner's bio
        enter.write("Writer's Name:\n%s\n" %(var));

        var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]/div/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
        print(var) #comments
        enter.write("Total Comments:\n%s\n" %(var));

        var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]/div/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
        print(var) #whatsapp
        enter.write("Whatsapp Share:\n%s\n" %(var));

        print()
        # driver.save_screenshot("captcha_%s.png"%(i))

    driver.back()

driver.quit()
enter.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. can you please share the cod you tried and the error that you got.

Comment: @supputuri thankyou for warm welcome :) Here is the code I have written till now, there is no error as nothing I do seems to get URL of post-images. https://ideone.com/ZzESLQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the refracted code. Added the tags and images logic at the end.

```
import sys
import csv
import os
import time
import urllib
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
serviceurl = 'https://sharechat.com/trending/Hindi'

files = "dataset_link_1.txt"
# if not os.path.exists(files):
#     file(files, 'w').close()
enter = open(files,'w');

url = serviceurl
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\CHIT CHAT\Scrapper\geckodriver');
driver.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
driver.get(url);
driver.implicitly_wait(3) #gives an implicit wait for 10 seconds
while driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") != 'complete':
    pass;

for i in range(1,20):

    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    #get the number of feeds
    feedCards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')]")
    for ifeedCard in range(len(feedCards)):
        # get Number of watches
        watches = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//div[contains(@class,'lhcaption')]/div[1]").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(watches)
        enter.write("Total No of views:\n%s\n" % (watches));
        # get title
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//span[contains(@class,'darkText')]").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(title)
        enter.write("Title:\n%s\n" % (title));
        # get owner bio
        writerBio = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//div[contains(@class,'Pstart')]//div[contains(@class,'darkTextSecondary')]").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(writerBio)
        enter.write("Writer's Bio:\n%s\n" % (writerBio));
        # get owner name
        writerName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//strong").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(writerName)
        enter.write("Writer Name:\n%s\n" % (writerName));
        # get comment
        comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//button[@aria-label='Click to comment']//span").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(comment)
        enter.write("Number of comments:\n%s\n" % (comment));
        # get share via whatsapp
        whatsApp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//button[@aria-label='Click to share']//span").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(whatsApp)
        enter.write("Whatsapp Share:\n%s\n" % (whatsApp));
        #get tags
        tags = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//div[contains(@class,'primaryDark')]").text.encode('utf-8')
        print(tags)
        enter.write("Tags:\n%s\n" % (tags));
        # get onwer image
        image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//img").get_attribute('src')
        print(image)
        enter.write("Owner Image link:\n%s\n" % (image));
        # post image
        postImage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')])[" + str(ifeedCard+1) + "]//a[@class='D(b)']").get_attribute('href')
        print(postImage)
        enter.write("post image link:\n%s\n" % (postImage))


driver.quit()
enter.close()
```

If you are trying to download the file to different folder. Use the below code.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'Here goes your folder where you want to download')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")
```

Once you download the file just use the below to rename the file to desired name.

```
os.rename(download_file_name,desired_name) # you can pass the file name with path.
```

Comment: Hi thanks! It doesn't run. I have updated my code and added link to geckodriver file. Just replace Line 18 with URL where you saved geckodriver and you can test your code locally. Thankyou for your time again :)

Comment: Check the updated code it should be perfect now (as tested the logic).

Comment: If you think the issue is resolved, please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark below the downvote button on the left hand side.

Comment: It stores post link but not the post content ( image/video ). Rest of it works! I see your approach is better than mine. I still can't understand how to grab post content using its link, kindly let me know so that I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Do you think best approach to get post-content is to simulate a click on bottom-rightmost download button? Or its not a good approach?

Comment: Do you want to download content? where do you want to store the post content?

Comment: Yes. We can save it directly to a folder in drive and store its filename in our text file. Storing on database would make it complicated i guess? Do you have better suggestions in your mind?

Comment: Option 1: use the download button and download the content then save the path. Option 2: use request module. Unfortunately I can not download the content on my machines due to security reasons.

Comment: I tried request module approach, but its not working because that link of that post again has a lot of elements just like original post. With first approach, as soon as i simulate a click on download, it just directly downloads the file so i dont get control over files name,etc :/

Comment: Haven't tried, but there are options to change the file as part of download. However, you can redirect the downloads to specific folder and then rename the file once the download is done.

Comment: Updated the answer with the profile needed for download.

Comment: hey! which tool did you use to find the relative x-path @supputuri?

Comment: Go to developer tools in chrome and then press "Ctrl+F" when you are in Elements tab. Then you can play with the xpath/css in the little search box. Were you able to download the file? We can close the thread by accepting the answer. Click on check mark below the down vote button on the left hand side in my answer.

Comment: I am not the owner of the question. Though I did upvote your answer.

Comment: Can you help me to click on the download button? I am not able to do it.

Comment: Also, I am finding the absolute path, not the relative path through the thing you told.

Comment: Can you give me the relative path of the download button? In case you can't help me downloading it.

Comment: Here is the xpath for download `//section[@class='post-batch']//div[contains(@class,'feedCard')]//button[@aria-label='Click to download']`. Basically you have to write the xpath in dev tools and test it. If you try to copy xpath you will get absolute xpath.

Comment: @supputuri Hey I couldn't get this working nor how did you come up with these neat relative xpaths ;( i tried installing few extensions for same but their output isn't as good), but since you have put a lot of efforts helping me out, I am marking this as Accepted Answer : )

Comment: I will just use the developer tools in the chrome browser for the xpath development and validation.

Answer (score 0):

I changes the web driver path and the range variable. If you create a folder  C:\Py my code below will output a text file with the called PageSource_StackOverflowQ2.txt with the image src paths.

I was having a lot of issues with binary characters in the htlm so there is probably a much better way to do this but hopefully this will help get you where you are trying to go.

If the image path contains these 9 characters in a row my code will brake
(" title=")

```
import sys
import csv
import os
import time
import urllib
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
serviceurl = 'https://sharechat.com/trending/Hindi'

# files = "dataset_link_1.txt"
enter = open('C:\\Py\\dataset_link_1.txt','w+')
# if not os.path.exists(files):
#     file(files, 'w').close()
# enter = open(files,'w');

url = serviceurl
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\CHIT CHAT\Scrapper\geckodriver');
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Py\\geckodriver.exe');
driver.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
driver.get(url);
driver.implicitly_wait(3) #gives an implicit wait for 10 seconds
while driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") != 'complete':
    pass;

# for i in range(1,20):
for i in range ( 1, 2 ):

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height


    var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/a/div[3]/div[1]"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
    print(var) #No of watches
    enter.write("Total No of views:\n%s\n" %(var));

    var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/a/div[1]/div[1]/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
    print(var) #Title
    enter.write("Title:\n%s\n" %(var));

    var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
    print(var) #owner bio
    enter.write("Writer's Bio:\n%s\n" %(var));

    var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[1]/strong"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
    print(var) #owner's bio
    enter.write("Writer's Name:\n%s\n" %(var));

    var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]/div/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
    print(var) #comments
    enter.write("Total Comments:\n%s\n" %(var));

    var = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[%s]/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]/div/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')
    print(var) #whatsapp
    enter.write("Whatsapp Share:\n%s\n" %(var));


    PageSource1 = [driver.page_source]
    PageSource1 = PageSource1[0].encode ( "utf-8" )

    file = open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ.txt', 'ab' )

    file.write ( PageSource1 )
    file.close ()
    FindPageCount = []

    file = open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ1.txt', 'w' )

    with open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ.txt', "rb" ) as outfile, open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ1.txt', "a" ) as f1:
        for line in outfile:
            uline = line.decode ( 'ascii', errors='ignore' )
            f1.write ( uline )
    outfile.close ()
    f1.close ()

    data = open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ1.txt', 'r' ).readlines ()
    with open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ1.txt' ) as f, open ( 'C:\\Py\\PageSource_StackOverflowQ2.txt', "w" ) as f1:
        data = f.readlines ()
        for i in range ( len ( data ) ):
            line = data[i]
            if ("img src" in line):
                q = line.split("><")
                for k in q:
                    if("img src" in k):
                        h = 0
                        while h < len ( k ):
                            l = h + 9
                            if k[h:l] == '" title="':
                                f1.write ( k[9:h] )
                                f1.write ( '\n' )
                                print ( h )
                                print ( k[9:h] )
                            h = h + 1


    print()
    # driver.save_screenshot("captcha_%s.png"%(i))

driver.back()

driver.quit()
enter.close()
```